# Express Checkout Digital Goods - tax line item doesn't display

Tags: paypal

I am calling SetExpressCheckout and handing in some tax. The Grand total in the paypal checkout screen reflects the tax (as expected) but there is no line item showing the tax. This is very confusing for customers. It appears like the grand total is "just higher" than the item price, for no apparent reason. I can't believe paypal would build it this way, so I assume I must be doing something wrong.

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Here is my REQUEST:

```
VERSION = 97.0
METHOD = SetExpressCheckout
RETURNURL = http://[removed...]
CANCELURL = http://[removed...]
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION = Sale
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE = USD
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT = 1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0 = Widget1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0 = Widget1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0 = 1
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT = 0.06
PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT = 1.06
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0 = 1
L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMCATEGORY0 = Digital
SOLUTIONTYPE = Sole
REQCONFIRMSHIPPING = 0
NOSHIPPING = 1
```

I also tried adding tax as an add'l "L_" line item for tax, but that makes it worse. It increases the line item itself by the tax amount, so the customer doesn't know they're paying tax, they just think the item price is higher.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you still need help but I found a way to add tax simply by adding the tax as an additional item.

This also allowed me to name the tax....:

```
// to add anothe item, uncomment the lines below and comment the line above 
$items[] = array('name' => 'TVA', 'amt' => $tvaAmount1, 'qty' => 1);
// $items[] = array('name' => 'Item Name2', 'amt' => $itemAmount2, 'qty' => 1);
$paymentAmount = $paymentAmount + $tvaAmount1;
```

Comment: Looks interesting, but I'm unclear how to integrate this. Looks like you've simply created an array. How does that fit with my posted code?